# Google Material 2 globally overriding the <md-toolbar> opacity and padding

Tags: angular-material2

`"@angular2-material/toolbar": "2.0.0-alpha.6-2"`

I want to change the background opacity and padding of the `<md-toolbar>` for my entire application.

My application is importing from `index.html`:

```
@import "default-theme";
@import 'variables';
@import 'overlay';
@import 'live-announcer';
```

I am using the Material 2 My thinking is that I need to somehow override these settings within the Material 2 `toolbar.scss` file (excerpted below):

```
md-toolbar {
  ...
  padding: 0 $md-toolbar-padding;
  ...
  background: md-color($md-background, app-bar);
}
```

I've dug into the `toolbar.js` file within the `vendor` folder and it appears to embed the entire `toolbar.css`... therefore it seems that the only place that I have the opportunity to override either of these style properties is within any of my components that use `MdToolbar` via my components' `stylesUrls`... *(btw: this does work)*

I'm guessing that I've missed something, because what I want to do seems like it would be a fairly common desire (although may it would be anathema to using Google Material --- I'm not certain how staunch the community is about elements such as padding, background transparency, and the like)... in either case my ignorance needs to be lifted in order to proceed with confidence.

Comment: I was just looking at this also (trying to change variables via sass), but looking at [this issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/123) and linked issues, doesn't look like it's (_easily_) possible right now. So I guess the styles method seems to be your best bet as of right now.

Comment: Yes, I had seen those comments a few days ago and it didn't connect with my current quandary... but you're right... to me it seems like customizing the themes should have been a key base requirement of the design... and the way that the code looks and the reaction to the requests to allow theme customization makes me believe that they have a project-centric perspective as opposed to an implementer's perspective (sure it's still alpha, but still...) this is sometimes a symptom of "agile" projects... architecture emerges primarily through refactroing